# ResourceTaskStart problem due to multiple resources in a seize

Tags: simulation, anylogic

A little insight into my project:

I am trying to simulate a 6-floor inpatient hospital building. Where the patients that come in stay for a night or two and then leave, super simple. However, I want to add the task so that nurses prepare the patients room beforehand and that has proven to be harder than expected. After having tried multiple different methods I seek for your help for inspiration.

To keep the model as simple as possible I have only one *Seize* for all the floors due to restriction on the number of blocks. In that *Seize* I call a function that differs all the floors apart:

[The seize for the rooms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAuvc.png)

[The function that differs the floor apart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPZfB.png)

A similar function is for the nurses, a simple if-sentence that returns the right nurses.

Now for the hard part, the *ResourceTaskStart*.

I have multiple *ResourcePools* for this one seize so I haven't been able to connect them somehow together with the *ResourceTaskStart*. I can't call an agent.parameter as I have been doing in all these functions. I have tried to create a variable that returns a number as seen in my second picture "floor1 = 1" as an example. These variables should direct the nurses to the right location as seen in the following picture.

[The ResourceTask set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6HBc.png)

As seen in the picture I have *ResourcePool* for each of the floors that are initiated by the *Seize* "Rooms". These *ResourceTaskStart* and *MoveTo* are as following:

[ResourceTaksStart block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBwcK.png)

[MoveTo Block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zb9ly.png)

However, when I run the model I keep getting a different error message for each run and on different time. Sometimes I have 88 patients go through with no problem, then 104 and even 244 patients but there always appears some error like these here:

First run:
Exception during discrete event execution
root.MoveToWard5: 
Unit root.ward5 not found in the units seized by 276

Second run:
Exception during discrete event execution
root.MoveToWard8: 
Unit root.ward8 not found in the units seized by 265

Third run:
Exception during discrete event execution
root.MoveToWard7: 
Unit root.ward7 not found in the units seized by 353

This mismatch in the error message makes it difficult for me to decode and I have no idea why this error is appearing.

My question: Do you have any idea what the problem might be or do you have any idea of a better way to simulate this problem?

If you need any more information please comment and I will provide them.

Comment: it's very likely that your floorx variable changes unexpectedly randomly in time when several resources are seized at the same time. If this is the problem it makes sense for your error to occur later. Your floor variable should be inside your nurse agent for this model to be solid

Comment: Hi @Felipe,

I think you are right with the error that it is related to the floors variables. I've been trying to work out your answer into my model and can't get it to work. When trying to do the if-sentence that determines the ward that the nurse should go to I run into problems.

I have tried this in *On prepare unit* in the Seize:

`if(agent.ward == 1){
 Nurses.Floor = 1;
}`

I have as well tried Nurse.unit.Floor = 1; and various other tries.

I have as well tried to insert these if sentences in *On seize* in the ResourcePool actions.

How can I communicate with Nurse agent?

Comment: you do it like this ((Nurse)unit).floor=1